# Write data to Excel sheet using Sahi Open Source

Tags: sahi

I am using Sahi Open Source. does anybody know how to write values to Excel Sheet using Sahi?

i am trying to read data from web page and store it to excel sheet in a given cell. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for:

http://sahi.co.in/w/working-with-excel-sheets

Answer (score 1):

Writing for Excel (or any other tool which understands CSV) is pretty simple. Just store your data in a two dimensional array and use the _writeCSVFile API: http://sahi.co.in/w/miscellaneous-apis

Regards
Wormi